# SQL error ORA-00920: invalid relational operator, and I don't know why

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm going to use regex_count and regex_like in one statement, but first I need to get count to work.  I don't understand why it is growing an error when these are valid columns, correct amount of parenthesis and I have the apostrophes.  Also using Oracle SQL Developer.

```
select employee_name, LTRIM(street)
from employee
where 
regexp_count( street, '[[:digit:]]' );
```

ORA-00920: invalid relational operator
00920. 00000 -  "invalid relational operator"
*Cause:
*Action:
Error at Line: 4 Column: 37

What I'm really trying to do is remove any starting street numbers from the street and return the result set.  I was going to use this below, and then figure out how to feed it into a substring function to get the result set i'm looking for.  Any suggestions?

```
select employee_name, LTRIM(street)
from employee
where 
regexp_like ( street, '[[:digit:]]', 1, regexp_count( street, '[[:digit:]]' ) );
```

Comment: For your revised problem, I would suggest sample data and desired results (and perhaps another question -- the revised question is different from the first one).

Comment: True, I will do that.  Thanks for help by the way.

Answer (score 2):

`REGEXP_COUNT()` returns an integer, not a boolean.  So, you need a comparison:

```
select employee_name, LTRIM(street)
from employee
where regexp_count( street, '[[:digit:]]' ) > 1;
```

If the comparison is just `> 0`, then you don't need to count the number of patterns.  Just use `regexp_like()`.

If you want to remove leading digits, use `regexp_substr()`:

```
select regexp_substr(street, '[^[:digit:]].*')
```